# DECODE with NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert ZEROS or Spaces when the value is `NULL`

I tried for small column length and it worked:

```
INSERT INTO ABCTABLE (COLUMN1) 
VALUES ('DECODE(MDSE_CD,NULL,''000'',LPAD(TO_NUMBER(MDSE_CD,''3'','' ''))');
```

But how do I execute the second query that has around 400 column length:

```
INSERT INTO ABCTABLE (COLUMN1) 
VALUES ('DECODE(MDSE_CD,NULL,''see notes below'',LPAD(TO_NUMBER(MDSE_CD,''400'','' ''))');
```

Note:How do I insert 400 zeros or spaces when the column is `NULL`

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? It can't be both!

Comment: Why on earth would anybody want four hundred zeroes in a column?  I know everybody says "storage is cheap"  but it's not that cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE my_test( val VARCHAR2(500));

INSERT INTO my_test
SELECT TO_CHAR(NVL(TO_CHAR(val), rpad(NVL(val,'0'), 400, '0')))
FROM
     (WITH t(val) AS
     (SELECT '1' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT NULL FROM dual
     )
SELECT * FROM t
     );

SELECT * FROM my_test;
val
--
1
00000
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `DECODE` I'm assuming Oracle...

To get 400 zeros in Oracle:

```
LPAD('0', 400, '0')
```

The third parameter is what to pad with; in this case zeros.

To get 400 spaces in Oracle:

```
LPAD(' ', 400)
```

Since the strings are all the same character you could also use `RPAD`.